# Validity of an iteration for Goodness of fit to a specific application

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, survey, goodness-of-fit

I am not a statistics expert and would like to check the validity of a test I hav used on a survey results.

**Survey Results**
I asked people ($n$=264) to characterize a panoramic road they chose in 24 different categories. Each of them could choose as many categories he/she desired. Than I counted the number of times each category was mentioned for two subsets of my sample: experts ($n$=37) and public ($n$=227). I received a distribution of the magnitude (or frequencies) for each category in each group.

**The Question**
I would like to check whether the distribution of choices in two subsets is the same. If it is different, I would like to know which categories are the cause fr this variance.

**The test**
I chose to use Goodness of Fit (Chi-Square) Using R, while `x=`(public counts) and `p=`(experts counts) with `rescale.p = TRUE`. I set my significance level to 5%.

Then I wrote a `while` loop, that works until the test's p-Value > 5%.

The loop omits variables in each iteration. Omitting variables is based upon a delta vector (`delta<-abs(public_counts - expert_counts`). For each iteration the variables that has the highest delta are omitted. That is until $H_0$ is accepted.

I would like to know if this extension of the chi.square function using the while loop is a valid method to answer my question. In particular, is the delta vector that is based on absolute counts is a correct specification.

I would be happy to provide raw data and code for my `multi.chi` function if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the implementation, I think your choice of test is wrong, unless those 37 experts are actually the *population*.

If instead they represent a sample of experts, then you would need to account also for the variation in the sample of experts from the population distribution they represent.

That is, you'd need a test of whether the two samples you have could plausibly have come from the same distribution or not.

It looks to me like you are in a situation something like a test of homogeneity instead.

If the expected counts aren't too small, this might be done as a chi-squared test ($2\times k$), or it might be done as some kind of exact (permuation/randomization) test - possibly even one using the chi-squared statistic.

---

Note that if you use a goodness of fit test, you're treating the experts' proportions as a fixed population vector when it's subject to sampling variation of its own.

Consequently the expert ratings are another set of sample counts that should be in the table ($k\times 2$ not $k\times 1$), and the test is not goodness of fit but heterogeneity of proportions.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. I'm find it difficult to understand the difference between the chi_squared test that you are describing to the one I chose. As I understood from browsing the web and R help is that the "Goosness of Fit" test is a version of chi squared and is being operated (in my code) by the command: `chisq.test(x=x,p=p,rescale.p=rescale.p)`, while x and p are my two counts. Isn't it the same?
Also, does it matter if I use p (public, n=227) as the main variable (x=p) and the experts (n=37) as my expected frequencies regarding the small size of my sample?

Comment: It is not the same, no.